# How to store the result of a radio button with a database value, back into the database?

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

Been stuck on this bit of code for a while now. What I'm doing in 'do_assignments.php' (below) is creating a loop that outputs each question in my database and every possible answer associated with that question.

```
<form method="post" action="user_storeresults.php"> $query = "SELECT * FROM questions, question_choices WHERE q_topic = 'PhoneGap' AND visible = 1 AND q_type = 'Multiple' AND questions.q_id = question_choices.question_id";
           $result=mysql_query($query); 


              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
                     if($row['q_id'] != @$qid){
                        echo "<h4><strong>" . $row['q_string'] . "</strong></h4>";
                        @$qid = $row['q_id']; 
                     }
                     echo "<input name='".$row['choice_id']."' value='".$row['correct_choice']."' type='radio' />";
                     echo $row['choice_string'] . "<br/>";

              }
              ?>
              <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><p>
              </form>
              <?php
```

The value of each radio button contains data from a field in 'correct_choice' in my database, where there is wrong answers (0) and a correct answer (1) associated with each question.

All of this works well, but because i'm trying to submit a post from a radio button that doesn't have a specific name or value (only what it retrieves from the database), i can't quite figure out how i would be able to retrieve these values in the next page 'user_storeresults.php'...

Any help would be much appreciated. If i'm being a bit too vague then say, and ill try and clear it up as much as possible.

Comment: Your radio buttons look like they have names and values to me

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not making that clear. I know they have names and values, but because these names and values are from different rows in the database, i'm unsure how to get the values and insert them into the database in the next file. Sorry for the confusion, still relatively new to PHP. I've done this before with simple radio names and values, not entirely sure why having database values makes this more difficult...

Comment: You would have to make it part of the name .. something like `name="QUESTIONID-ANSWERID"`